# Cannot reboot the laptop using an external monitor. Boot stalls

Tags: boot, nvidia, power-management, laptop, external-monitor

I'm having issues rebooting my laptop using the external monitor and the laptop docked with the lid closed.

I tried out the live version of Ubuntu using the laptop with the lid closed and my monitor as the primary. This was also the configuration that I had when I installed Ubuntu.

When I first restarted the system (lid closed, using external monitor), after the Ubuntu splash screen the laptop suspended/hibernated. When powered it up the disk was accessed for a while but the login screen never appeared.
If I reboot with the lid open it works fine and I can close the lid and use the laptop through the external monitor normally except if I close the lid before login. Then it sleeps/hibernates immediately but recovers successfully when powered up.

**Solutions tested:**

1. Installed the Gnome tweak tool and deselected "suspend when lid is close" - didn't work
2. In /etc/UPower/UPower.conf selected IgnoreLid=true - didn't work
3. Went to the nvidia Xserver settings and disabled the laptop monitor and made the external monitor primary - Didn't work. Actually when I reboot seems the settings go back to the laptop monitor being the primary
4. Edited logind.conf #HandleLidSwitch=ignore and #HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore - didn't work
5. Disabled the laptop monitor in Nvidia Xserver settings - didn't work

These were all the possible solutions that I found in the forum but none worked.

**System** - I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS with Gnome 3.36.8 in a HP Elitebook 8560w laptop.
I'm using an external Dell monitor.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Edo

Answer (score 0):

Newbie mistake

When I went back to look at logind.conf understood that the # was comment sign in this program language.
I took out the comments in HandleLidSwitch=ignore and HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore and now it works just fine.

I'll leave this question as it compiles several possibilities for those who need to solve this problem.